# Adding labels to cut function in R

Tags: r

For an example dataframe:

```
df1 <- structure(list(X = 1:15, a = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 5L, NA, 2L, 
9L, 7L, 0L, 1L, 20L, 15L, 14L)), .Names = c("X", "a"), 
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

I am using the following code to divide column 'a' into quartiles:

```
cut.at.n.tile <- function(X , n = 4){ 
  cut( X , breaks = quantile( X , 
     probs = (0:n)/n , na.rm = TRUE ) , include.lowest = TRUE )}
df1$a.quartile <- cut.at.n.tile( df1$a , n = 4)
```

How do I replace the labels with 1 - 4 (1 being the lowest)?  I don't wish to simply recode the values as I will be running this lots of times with different continuous variables.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `labels` argument to `cut` ...

```
cut.at.n.tile <- function(X , n = 4){ 
   cut( X , breaks = quantile( X , 
      probs = (0:n)/n , na.rm = TRUE ) ,
      labels = 1:n,
      include.lowest = TRUE )}
cut.at.n.tile( df1$a , n = 4)
##  [1] 1    2    2    2    3    3    <NA> 1    4    3
##      1    1    4    4    4   
## Levels: 1 2 3 4
```

You might also be interested in `ggplot2::cut_number`, which does
essentially the same thing ...

```
ggplot2::cut_number(df1$a, n = 4, labels = 1:4)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also just set labels to FALSE within the cut fcn; i.e.,

```
cut(df1$a,
    breaks = quantile( df1$a , 
                     probs = seq(0,1,.25) , na.rm = TRUE ),
    labels = F, # setting labels to false just makes labels integer codes instead of factor levels
    include.lowest = T)
```