# In R (or RStudio) I want to convert a field with units to a number, but I get erroneous warnings

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

Using R, I have data that looks like:

```
A,   B
=  =====
x,"  120"
y," 2300"
z,"1.2 M"
x," 4500"
x," 42 M"
```

This was constructed using:

```
A <- c("x","y","z","x","x")
B <- c("  120", " 2300", "1.2 M", " 4500", " 42 M")
data <- data.frame(A, B)
```

I want to convert the second column to a valid number (the 'M' signifies millions). What I have is:

```
df <- data %>%
    mutate( B = ifelse( grepl("^ *[0-9]+$", .$B), 
                        as.numeric(.$B),
                        1000000 * as.numeric(sub(" *([0-9]+) M", "\\1", .$B))))
```

ie. it looks for a field with an 'M', and if found does as.numeric on the sustricg and multiplies by 1000000.

This works fine, EXCEPT I get a warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: Problem with `mutate()` input `B`.
i NAs introduced by coercion
i Input `B` is `ifelse(...)`. 
2: In ifelse(grepl("^ *[0-9]+$", .$B), as.numeric(.$B), 1e+06 *  :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

But when I inspect the data using `df %>% filter(is.na(B))`, there are no NAs

I don't want to disable the warning entirely, but I do want to avoid it when it's "invalid".

Any suggestions? Ami I missing something?

Comment: You should not be using `.$` within `grepl` (within `mutate`). While it works here, it's bad practice and will cause either failure (best case) or silent corrupted data if you aren't careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a function, not completely tested, that's a companion to [another I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63459431/3358272) (that is based loosely off of `utils:::format.object_size`).

```r
unKMG <- function(s, standard = "SI") {
  known_bases <- c(legacy = 1024, IEC = 1024, SI = 1000)
  known_units <- list(SI = c("", "k", "M", "G", "T", "P", 
      "E", "Z", "Y"), IEC = c("", "Ki", "Mi", "Gi", 
      "Ti", "Pi", "Ei", "Zi", "Yi"), legacy = c("", "K", 
      "M", "G", "T", "P"))
  standard <- match.arg(standard, c("auto", names(known_bases)))
  powers <- known_bases[[standard]] ^
    (setNames(seq_along(known_units[[standard]]), known_units[[standard]])-1)
  sapply(strsplit(trimws(s), "[[:space:]]+"),
         function(z) {
           nums <- suppressWarnings(as.numeric(z))
           prod(nums[!is.na(nums)], powers[names(powers) %in% z[is.na(nums)]])
         })
}

unKMG(dat$B)
# [1]      120     2300  1200000     4500 42000000
```

But if you want a one-shot approach, try

```r
as.numeric(gsub(".*\\b(-?[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*)\\b.*", "\\1", dat$B)) * 
  ifelse(grepl("M", dat$B), 1000000, 1)
# [1]      120     2300 12000000     4500 42000000

dat %>%
  mutate(
    B = as.numeric(gsub(".*\\b(-?[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*)\\b.*", "\\1", B)) * 
          ifelse(grepl("M", B), 1000000, 1)
  )
```

Explanation of the regex:

- `.*` *anything* (including nothing)
- `\\b` a word-boundary, not consumed (included); this ensures we don't start or end a number in the middle of a larger number, for instance
- `(...)` group, is referenced in the second argument as `\\1`
- `-?` 0 or 1 of the negative sign
- `[0-9]+` 1 or more digits
- `\\.?` 0 or 1 of the decimal point (replace with `,` or `[,.]` for different locales)
- `[0-9]*` *0 or more* digits

(I named my data `dat`, if you hadn't noticed ... I've been bitten too many times by errors about `invalid 'type' (closure) of argument` when I misplaced my `data` that now I tend to use other names that do not collide with base R functions.)

Comment: Thank you! yes, I'll file away the first one, and use the one-shot for now...it's MUCH better than mine.

Comment: If you ever have decimals, the `gsub` might need to be adjusted. While `"[^0-9.]"` is a quick attempt, it will allow `"1.2.3"`, which won't work in `as.numeric`. If you want to deal with negatives, that too is a little more complex. In which case, one might need something like my (seconds-ago) recent edit.

Comment: lol...was about to add that slight change, since I do need decimals. Thank you again.

Comment: Because I want the conversion to fail if the field is not exactly what I expect, I went with ```gsub("(^\\s*|\\s*M\\s*$)", "", data$B))```. This will also handle signs and scientific notation etc. Basically it assumes <optional-space><non-space><optional-space>M<optional-space>, and treats <non-space> as a number.

Answer (score 3):

The *reason* why you get the warning is because `ifelse`/`if_else`/`case_when` pass the entire vector in both `yes` and `no` part. The output to return is later decided based on the condition.

So we think that we are applying `as.numeric(B)` to only those numbers that satisfy the condition but in reality it is same as applying `as.numeric(data$B)` which gives the same warning that few values in `B` cannot be converted to numeric. So you need to use `ifelse` in a way that doesn't generate a warning at all for any value (which is shown by @r2evans already) or apply the manipulation separately without `ifelse`.

```
data$C <- NA_real_
inds <- grepl("^ *[0-9]+$", data$B)
data$C[inds] <- as.numeric(B[inds])
data$C[!inds] <- 1000000 * as.numeric(sub(" *([0-9]+) M", "\\1", data$B[!inds]))
```

Comment: Thanks for addressing the underlying question, whereas I just went to resolve the symptom.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the explanation:this seems like an opportunity for (a) optimization and (b) multithreading...