# Formatting R plotly tooltips ($ 3.5 B or 6.7 M, for example)

Tags: r, shiny, tooltip

I created some tooltips for a graph I made in R. My tooltip displays both Year and Cost. Sometimes, cost is a large number (e.g., millions or billions). Can I have R automatically express the tooltip in terms of millions of billions (whatever is appropriate given the inputs)?

The data is being read into the R Shiny reactive graph from a reactive dataframe I made.

Here is an image of the current behavior. The cost is somewhat unreadable.

[image]

Here is how I'm specifying the tooltip:

```
# Specify tooltip fields here
p <- ggplotly(gg, tooltip = c("Year", "Cost"))
```

Comment: You don't need to include [tag:shiny] or [tag:plotly] in this question if you already know how to make a basic tooltip. What you need to know how to do is convert a number to a human-readable numbers, in which case https://stackoverflow.com/q/63459178/3358272 should resolve your issue (disregarding the `factor`/`levels=` notion of that question), where `KMG(c(1, 12345, 1.2345e6, 1.2345e9))` produces `c("1", "12.3k", "1.2M", "1.2G")`.

Answer (score 2):

You did not provide a reproducible example, so I created one myself.

Assuming you have something like this -

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(scales)

df <- data.frame(Cost = c(1e6, 12345678, 1e7), Year = factor(2001:2003))
gg <- ggplot(df, aes(Year, Cost)) + geom_point()
p <- ggplotly(gg, tooltip = c("Year", "Cost"))  
p
```

[image]

`scales` package has a very nice function to handle such cases. I have created a new column in this case but you can also overwrite the same column if you wish.

```
df$Cost_New <- label_number(accuracy = 0.1, 
                 scale_cut = cut_short_scale())(df$Cost)
gg <- ggplot(df, aes(Year, Cost_New)) + geom_point()
p <- ggplotly(gg, tooltip = c("Year", "Cost_New"))  
p
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this example @Ronak Shah ! I am getting an error "Discrete value supplied to continuous scale" on my bar plot. Any suggestions?